# print line number, first few characters of matching line and nth line after matching UNIX

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, unix-timestamp

I am using

```
awk '/^E/ {a=substr($0,1,26);n=NR} NR==n+2 && n {print n,a,$0}' logfile
```

but i want to pass the either date or timestamp **as parameter to the shell script** coming after `E`(want to fetch line which always starts with `E`). suppose if i give input as `2014-04-03` to the below file(2 lines as per below input file), it should fetch line starting with `E` and match the date and display the output for all the entries of that date

Expected output

```
line number | E 2014-04-03 12:11:41.853 |location=PIN_ERR_FM:5 class=PIN_ERR_APPLICN:4 errno=PIN_ERR_VALUE:46
```

inputfile is like below

```
E 2014-04-03 12:11:41.853  abm310  cm:21.-142726944  functionalpurchase.c:1821 1:Isa-P
        funcitional_aply_elmt eror
        <location=PIN_ERR_FM:5 class=PIN_ERR_APPLICN:4 errno=PIN_ERR_VALUE:46
        <field num=PIN__T:8,62 recid=0 reserved=0 reserved2=0 time(sec:usec)=1396548701:>

D 2014-04-03 12:11:41.853  abm310  cmf:2.-142726944  funtionalpurchase.c:1767 1:Isa-PC:
        Now apply the good fee
        <location=debugstate.c;class not found;errno=not found:01

E 2014-04-03 12:11:41.853  abm310  cm:21.-142726944  functionalpurchase.c:1821 1:Isa-P
        <location=PIN_ERR_FM:5 class=PIN_ERR_APPLICN:4 errno=PIN_ERR_VALUE:47>
        <field num=PIN__T:8,62 recid=0 reserved=0 reserved2=0 time(sec:usec)=1396548701:>
        <facility=0 msg_id=85 version=1>
```

Note: the  line starting as  `<location...` is also to be fetched for that sometime going to 2nd line or 3rd line or to 4th line after pattern match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this some you like?

```
awk '/^E/ {a=$0;n=NR} NR==n+2 && n {print n,a,$0}' file
1 E 45907:000:39   Error type, meant to find solution
```

This prints the line number for the line starting with `E`, then the line, then second line after that.

Updated to get only 7 characters from trigger line.

awk '/^E 20[0-9][0-9]/ {d=$1 FS $2 FS $3;f=1;n=NR} f && /location/ {$1=$1;gsub(/[<>]/,"");print n,d,$0;f=0}' OFS=\|
1|E 2014-04-03 12:11:41.853|location=PIN_ERR_FM:5|class=PIN_ERR_APPLICN:4|errno=PIN_ERR_VALUE:46
10|E 2014-04-03 12:11:41.853|location=PIN_ERR_FM:5|class=PIN_ERR_APPLICN:4|errno=PIN_ERR_VALUE:47

---

From your new data I only print data if line starts with `E` (could be `D` if you like or any):

```
awk '/^E 20[0-9][0-9]/ {d=$1 FS $2 FS $3;f=1;n=NR} f && /location/ {$1=$1;gsub(/[<>]/,"");print n,d,$0;f=0}' OFS=\| file
1|E 2014-04-03 12:11:41.853|location=PIN_ERR_FM:5|class=PIN_ERR_APPLICN:4|errno=PIN_ERR_VALUE:46
10|E 2014-04-03 12:11:41.853|location=PIN_ERR_FM:5|class=PIN_ERR_APPLICN:4|errno=PIN_ERR_VALUE:47
```

Comment: After pattern match i want only 7 character shud be printed from matching line. from the above output i want" 1 E 45907 Error type, meant to find solution ". Not to print whole matching line.

Comment: This is your expected output `line number E 45907:000:39 Error type, meant to find solution`. Close to what I have.

Comment: Dear Jonte ,bravoo and i need to print line number, only 7 characters starting from the pattern match(including 'E') , 2nd line from the pattern match. output like "1 E 45907 Error Type, Meant to find solution"

Comment: Dear Jonte, if i want to pass my inputs as argument to awk what changes i have to do, in the above case the Starting character 'E' will be same and i want to pass the time or date as parameter. can you help to do it shell script way.while patter match it shud consider E and parameter iam sending to the script u given.

Comment: @Srini Can you edit your original post with what you like to have as output from what data.

Comment: @Jonte i have updated the post, iam new to scripting, want to pass the parameters either date or timestamp as input. i)if i give timestamp it shud fetch all the entries starting with E till the last record for current date starting from that time, ii)if i give date all entries for that date starting with E

Comment: @Jonte after the '|' symbol i given the input file name, its giving msg -bash: pinlog: command not found

Comment: I dont want that line starting with 'D' and following lock of lines, i want to have line Starting with 'E' and its location, then next pattern match shud be done in next next line having E as start.

Comment: Try to change `OFS=\|` to `OFS="|"`.  Also make 100% sure all spaces are there.

Comment: Is it possible to include this command into script and store the results to a file and then i to pass date or timestamp as input parameter to fetch necessary records matching the date ?

Comment: To save output of an `awk` to variable do: `var=$(awk 'commands')`

Comment: @Jonte:- suppose awk is saving the results to file2, then i want to process the file through command line arguments, like this ./srini1 2014-04-04, now it shud return results matching the date 2014-04-04.\n  my script is like below (dont laugh).:- awk '/^E 20[0-9][0-9]/ {d=$1 FS $2 FS $3;f=1;n=NR} f && /location/ {$1=$1;gsub(/[<>]/,"");print n,d,$0;f=0}' OFS='|' cm.pinlog >cmerror
if $1=0
  if $2=0
   cat cmerror | sed -n -e '/$3/'
  fi
fi

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '/^E/{=;N;N;s/^(.{15}).*\n.*\n\s*/\1/p}' file | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

This prints the line number of the required line and the then reads and appends the next two lines and returns the extracted strings. The output is piped to another sed which reduces every two lines to a single line.

Comment: @ Potong:- i have one script i sh1.sh with one line" awk '/^E 20[0-9][0-9]/ {d=$1 FS $2 FS $3;f=1;n=NR} f && /location/ {$1=$1;gsub(/[<>]/,"");print n,d,$0;f=0}' OFS='|' filename"  and another script sh2.sh which used arguments. here i want to call the sh1.sh inside sh2.sh. while running i pass arguments to sh2.sh arg1 arg2. will this arguments effect the sh1.sh arguments or sh1.sh runs first and then sh2.sh with arguments ?